# Error in callback bound method UserNamespaceCommandHook.post_command_execute on read a Big query table from PySpark on Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, databricks

Am trying to read a table from Google Big query via Pyspark on Databricks platform.

**Approach 1:**

Am using the native Spark feature for reading the table. It is working fine for the Partitioned tables when the partition filter is not mandate on read, whereas for the table the partition filter is mandate to read am facing an issue.

**Code Snippet used to read:**

```
read_df = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
    .option("parentProject","valid_parent_project_name")\
    .option("project", "valid_project_name")\
    .option("dataset", "valid_dataset_name")\
    .option('table', "investment") \
    .load()
```

Above **investment** table is partitioned by **update_date** and it is mandate to add the filter on read the table. Have tried to add the partition filter in multiple ways by applying filter, where and query options on read statement, but no luck.

**Error:**

`Error in callback <bound method UserNamespaceCommandHook.post_command_execute of <dbruntime.DatasetInfo.UserNamespaceCommandHook object at 0x7fba9d58ab30>> (for post_execute):`

**Approach 2:**
Using the library **com.google.cloud.spark:spark-3.3-bigquery:0.32.2** to read the big query table.

**Code snippet used to read:**

```
spark.conf.set("viewsEnabled","true")
spark.conf.set("materializationDataset","project_id.dataset_id.table_name")
spark.conf.set("materializationProject", "project_id.dataset_id.table_name")

sql="SELECT * FROM project_id.dataset_id.table_name WHERE TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(update_date, DAY) = TIMESTAMP('2023-10-10') LIMIT 1000"
df = spark.read.format("bigquery").load(sql)
display(df)
```

**Error:**

```
Multiple sources found for bigquery (com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider, com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.v2.Spark33BigQueryTableProvider),
 please specify the fully qualified class name.
```

***Sample query to read the data on Bigquery console:***

```
"SELECT * FROM project_id.dataset_id.table_name WHERE TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(update_date, DAY) = TIMESTAMP('2023-10-10') LIMIT 1000"
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
**Note:** Service account is having the required access to read the tables.

Comment: Are you on GCP Databricks or other clouds?

Comment: @AlexOtt Yes, It's on GCP Databricks.